# In python the decimal numbers in appended list from a CSV becomes single quoted. How do I change the elements to int or float?

Tags: python, csv

After appending a list with one column(with string header and decimal numbers) from a CSV file, the numbers become single quoted in the list. Cant do a sum etc. I popped the header after the list was populated. Also tried appending list without the header. Same problem.Any way that I can remove the quotes and convert the elements to floating numbers Example of what my list looks like:

```
['22.13', '17.25', '16.05666666666667', '16.94', '17.0', '16.083333333333332', '15.09', '15.9', '14.213333333333333', '12.246666666666666']
```

I have plenty more to do but stuck at this point. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The elements in your list are strings. You need to cast them to floats.

```
[float(x) for x in my_list]
```

Comment: works fine but this should also work right? it didnt work earlier but works this way now.                                    reader = csv.reader(open("shortfloat.txt","rb"))
for row in reader:
     cpu_util.append(float(row[2]))

Comment: I guess I have to do this after, if the header was still in, while appending the list.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you are using python's [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module.

Quoting the docs:

> Each row read from the csv file is returned as a list of strings. No
>   automatic data type conversion is performed.

Your only choice is to typecast the list after reading from the file. Following one liner will do it for you:

```
mylist = map(float, mylist)
```

Comment: works also. Why cant I change to float while reading in the csv file. I tried this - cpu_util.append(float(row[2])) - in the for loop while reading in the file and it works. For some strange reason it wasnt working earlier.

Comment: Thats because csv file reader won't automatically know the data types of the columns. You can always write a custom wrapper around csv reader to guess the data types and convert them accordingly. If the provided solution worked, you can probably accept an answer.

Comment: Already mentioned that both Chris and your answers work just fine. I missed the square brace in my for loop.                          reader = csv.reader(open("VSrvCurCon_semi.csv","rb"))
next (reader)  ## skip the header row
for row in reader:
     cpu_util.append(float(row[2]))

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using `csv.Reader` from the stdlib, note the following from the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader):

> Each row read from the csv file is returned as a list of strings. No
>   automatic data type conversion is performed.

You'll have to call `float()` on your number columns to convert from a string to a float. If all of your values are floats, you could use a list comprehension:

```
row = [float(value) for value in row]
```